# how to compose html code within onload() function?

Tags: javascript, html

Within body I have 3 div: menu, submenu, detail.
I'm using script load_menu() in menu div to load html code to submenu div.
I'm using script load_data() in submenu div to load html code to detail div.
In both scripts I use the fetch method.
Up to now everything works fine.

I would like to load the first submenu item after loading submenu div, using onload() function. I don't know how to reform the submenu line into proper syntax in the onload() function.

Next is parts from my code:

1. scrips definition:

```js
<script>
    function load_menu(htmname) {
        fetch(htmname /*, options */)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((html) => {
                document.getElementById("submenu").innerHTML = html;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.warn(error);
            });
    }
    function load_data(htmfile) {
        fetch(htmfile /*, options */)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((html) => {
                document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML = html;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.warn(error);
            });
    }
    
    function loadfirst() {
          /*  load_data("./iNat_files/PID297.html"); ???? */
    }
</script>
```

```html
/* menu item executed onclick */
<li><a href="#submenu" onclick=load_menu("./iNat_files/P_menu.html") onload="loadfirst()">Plants</a></li>

/* the first submenu item to fetch - to be adapted and reformed for use with onload() */
<li><a href="#detail" onclick=load_data("./iNat_files/PID297.html")># 297:  = Centaurea crocodylium</a></li>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. Is the data you're fetching not correctly going into the divs? If so, can you show us the structure of the data and how you want it transformed into HTML?

Comment: My question is - how to code the loadfirst() function in order load (fetch) a html flie into detail div or how to simulate the **onclick** function used in the submenu code.

Comment: To focus on my issue:
The submeue  contains a list of one to many lines, all of the same format (but different html files to load):

" **<li><a href="#detail" onclick=load_data("./iNat_files/PID297.html")># 297:  = Centaurea crocodylium</a></li>** "

I want to simulate the first submenu line to be executed, immediately after the submenu is loaded, using the onload() javascript function. The question is:  how to code it ? 

I know which file should be loaded by first submenu line, so it will be hard coded (not an argument to the script).

Comment: The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) page has some simple examples. If I understand correctly, it would be something like `window.onload = (event) => loadFirst();`

Comment: @Robert, all the examples diaplay a message. My aim is to **load** a html file into another div, so it doen't help me. Anyhow, thanks for the esponse.

Comment: I solved my issue. No need of onload() function. I had just to call two scripts while loading the submenu, as in next code:  **<li><a href="#submenu" onclick=load_menu("./iNat_files/P_menu.html");load_data("./iNat_files/PID297.html")>Plants</a></li>**